# Googlesheet with Flutter : invalid_grant Invalid JWT

Tags: android, flutter, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

So, I've spent the past 2 hours searching for a solution for this but I cannot get anywhere.
I've followed this [link](https://medium.com/@a.marenkov/how-to-get-credentials-for-google-sheets-456b7e88c430) to setup the google sheet API in order to use it with Flutter.
I keep getting this error:

> ServerRequestFailedException (Failed to obtain access credentials. Error: invalid_grant Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim. Status code: 400)

As far as I've seen, this is related to a time problem but I've made sure the device's time is correct + enabled auto setting in the settings.
I'm using an android emulator (Pixel 4 API 27)

These are 2 pictures to show my time settings:
[image]
[image]

My code: (I'm calling the initSheet() in main)

```
class SpreadSheet {
  static late final gsheets;
  static late final spreadsheet;

  static Future<bool> initSheet() async {
    // TODO: Handle errors (Wrong time....)
    gsheets = GSheets(_credentials);

    /// link looks like so https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID/edit#gid=0
    /// [YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID] in the path is the id your need
    spreadsheet = await gsheets
        .spreadsheet("1t51H_CSHPFoKB7KW_AcGMi3gwyJnecfM_k5wvk4OQ04");
    return (spreadsheet == null ? false : true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, the code is running perfectly now.
I used `flutter clean` & had to re-download gradle-6.9 zip because it got corrupted somehow.
I still don't know if that's exactly what actually fixed it or no but it'll be worth the try if someone faces this problem again.